# org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "enum" is not a defined name

Tags: avro

I'm using following tool

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>tech.allegro.schema.json2avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

to convert json to avro, but I'm getting exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: "enum" is not a defined name. The type of the "enumValue" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.
at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1265)
at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1032)
at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:997)
... removed by me, our code ...
```

for avro schema:

```
{
  "namespace": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "enumValue",
      "type": "enum",
      "symbols": [
        "val_a",
        "val_b"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and json:

```
{
  "enumValue": "val_a"
}
```

dependency tree shows avro 1.8.2

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.7.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] +- tech.allegro.schema.json2avro:converter:jar:0.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- info.picocli:picocli:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

while enum definition seems to be quite the same as the one from avro home page:

```
For example, playing card suits might be defined with:

{ "type": "enum",
  "name": "Suit",
  "symbols" : ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
}
```

So what can be wrong here? Definitions seems to be OK (is it?), latest avro seems to be used and that one should support enums. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was wrong, correct definition looks like:

```
{
  "namespace": "test",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "enumValue",
      "type": {
        "name": "EnumType",
        "type": "enum",
        "symbols": [
          "val_a",
          "val_b"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: but yet the example you ref suggests otherwise

Comment: I probably don't understand. What is wrong in your opinion?

Comment: Your original code seems to match the cards example provided by Avro docs perfectly but yet you have to implement differently to work. Seems the docs are found in want

Comment: Yes avro documentation is sometimes hard to read/find. What's found in avro homepage as enum definition is element, which is value of "type" element. Anyways, if you compare avro in question and aswer it should show the difference; the example in avro homepage isn't incorrect, it's just not complete and it might be slightly misguiding.